# DateListPlot with two time list adding 2 labels, and setting the color of the label and lines in plot

Tags: plotting, labeling

This command will produce a chart with two lines on it.

```
DateListPlot[{CapReg, Equity},  Joined -> True ]
```

What I would like to do is add a label above the chart "CapReg" in red, and a label below the chart "Equity" in blue. Then I would like to have the color of the `CapReg` line be red, and the line for `Equity` be blue. Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You've looked into `PlotStyle`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following?

```
 data1 = {{{2006, 10, 1}, 10}, {{2006, 10, 15}, 12}, 
          {{2006, 10, 30},15}, {{2006, 11, 20}, 20}};
 data2 = {{{2006, 10, 5}, 15}, {{2006, 10, 20}, 8}, 
          {{2006, 11, 10},  5}, {{2006, 11, 15}, 1}};
 DateListPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Joined -> True,
 PlotLabel ->  Row[{Style["CapReg", Red, "Section"],Spacer[15],
                    Style["Equity", Blue, "Section"]}]]
```

[image]

EDIT: For placing parts of plot label in various places, you can use option `FrameLabel` or the built-in function `Labeled` as follows:

```
DateListPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Joined -> True,
FrameLabel -> {{"values", None}, {Column[{"dates", Style["Equity", Blue, "Section"]}, 
 Alignment -> Center], Style["CapReg", Red, Bold, "Section"]}}]
```

[image]

```
 Labeled[
 DateListPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Joined -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"values", None}, {"dates", None}}], 
  {Style["CapReg", Red, Bold, "Section"], Style["Equity", Blue, Bold, "Section"]},
  {Top, Bottom}]
```

[image]

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, thank you for the edit:) I was puzzled for a second itlooked as if Ctrl-C was enough to cut and paste into the right place in SE :)

Comment: No worries. Also minor change in using Spacer rather than a string space. I prefer Spacer since it allows more flexibility.

Comment: Thank you, it works good. Is there any way the "Equity" la bel could be placed under the Chart?

Comment: @John, you can use `FrameLabel` or `Labeled` to place the labels in various places. I will edit the post with examples in a moment.

Comment: kguler, thank you for your help. Hope you have a good weekend.